# Find every Hamiltonian path through a 4x4 matrix starting from a given X,Y?

Tags: hamiltonian-path

As part of programming a game, I'm trying to generate all the paths through an NxN matrix that touch every cell once without revisiting any, starting from (0,0). Considering the matrix as a graph, each such path in a 4x4 matrix would then contain 16 vertices and 15 edges. Each step of the path can only move 1 matrix cell in any direction, including diagonal.

How might I do this?

**Edit**, I believe I have successfully written a DFS to do this, but I found that it can only calculate it for up to a 4x4. If tried on a 5x5, the computer hangs indefinitely. Presumably the number of paths for a 5x5 is in the 9 digit range, so I think it could be calculated but it would take awhile. But a 6x6 could not be calculated in any reasonable timeframe this way.

I suppose this is quadratic growth as it went from 188 solutions that start from 0,0 of a 3x3 matrix to 37,948 solutions that start from 0,0 on a 4x4. So the 5x5 would have a bit over a billion if that's right.

Here is the code I used:

```
type Position = [number, number];

const n = 4;
const paths: Position[][] = [];

const directions: Position[] = [
  [-1, -1], [-1, 0], [-1, 1],
  [0, -1],           [0, 1],
  [1, -1],  [1, 0],  [1, 1]
];

// Checks if a given position is valid within an NxN matrix
function isValid(x: number, y: number, visited: boolean[][]): boolean {
  return x >= 0 && y >= 0 && x < n && y < n && !visited[x][y];
}

function getValidVerticesFromHere(A: Position, visited: boolean[][]): Position[] {
  const valids: Position[] = [];
  for (const [dx, dy] of directions) {
    const newX = A[0] + dx;
    const newY = A[1] + dy;
    if (isValid(newX, newY, visited)) {
      valids.push([newX, newY]);
    }
  }
  return valids;
}

function deepcopy(matrix: boolean[][]): boolean[][] {
  return matrix.map(row => [...row]);
}

function markVisited(matrix: boolean[][], position: Position) {
  matrix[position[0]][position[1]] = true;
}

function findPaths(visited: boolean[][], path: Position[]) {
  const vertices = getValidVerticesFromHere(path[path.length - 1], visited);

  if (vertices.length === 0) {
    if (path.length === n * n) {
      paths.push(path);
    }
    return;
  }

  const newVisited = deepcopy(visited);
  markVisited(newVisited, path[path.length - 1]);

  for (const v of vertices) {
    const newPath = [...path, v];
    findPaths(newVisited, newPath);
  }
}

const visited: boolean[][] = Array.from({ length: n }, () => Array(n).fill(false));

findPaths(visited, [[0, 0]]);

console.log(paths);
```